# Soft keyboard show/hide make Gridview adapter getview call many times

Tags: android, gridview

I have two fragments: FragmentA, FragmentB.

FragmentA contains a GridView, using BaseAdapter subclass as adapter.

FragmentB contains a EditText, which will bring up soft keyboard when focus.

By pressing one grid of FragmentA's GridView, using  FragmentTransaction to add FragmentB to activity.

**The problem comes, when keyboard shows/hids in FragmentB, the getView method of FragmentA's adapter will be called many times, passing position:0, making bad performance.**

So anyone can explain why?

Comment: did you find a solution to avoid this? I have been facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior for adapters. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/TErt3iL-RZQ

Comment: can I avoid this call? I use fragment instead of activity as ui interface page, this call will make my app very bad performance.

Comment: If your code is dependent on the number of times getView() is called for a particular position then you are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: I have many fragments in a activity, so when keyboard show/hide, all the adapter in these fragments(with listview or gridview) will be called, so the performance is pool..